# EF6 Entity Core mapping issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

Im using EF 6.1.3 in one of my projects and recently i came across an interesting Error. When ever i use the Investigation class below in a select query, its throwing the error attached below.

The Errors gets resolved once i replace the Entity Framework specific dlls on the server. but i can not do this production. Can anyone help me understand anything about this error to see how it can be resolved?

Table Definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Investigation](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Investigation_CreatedOn]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [AssignedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DueBy] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastModified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IsSent] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Investigation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The Model class is

```
public partial class Investigation
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Investigation()
        {
            InvestigationHistories = new HashSet<InvestigationHistory>();
            Investigators = new HashSet<Investigator>();
            SubTopicInvestigationAssocs = new HashSet<SubTopicInvestigationAssoc>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int StatusId { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? AssignedOn { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? DueBy { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

        public Guid LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public bool IsSent { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<InvestigationHistory> InvestigationHistories { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Investigator> Investigators { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SubTopicInvestigationAssoc> SubTopicInvestigationAssocs { get; set; }
    }
```

The Error.

> Error: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> ***System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: The query view generated for the EntitySet 'Investigations' is not valid. The query parser threw the following error : The argument type 'Edm.DateTime' is not compatible with the property 'LastModifiedBy' of formal type 'Edm.Guid'. Near member access expression,*** line 3, column 112..
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView.GetCommandTree()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView.GetInternalTree(Command targetIqtCommand)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.ProcessJoinOp(Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitJoinOp(JoinBaseOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.Object

Comment: Could you add the definition of the table this maps to?

Comment: Added to the question. @NickBailey

Comment: Any luck? I have similar issue

Comment: I resolved the issue by adding column type parameters to all properties in the model